# Access Value Of 1 Field into another in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to use my column data in other columns for arithmetic operations. I am fetching data using join. Is there a way to access this data by index. However, table is same. I am using postgresql. Hopes for suggestion

Comment: If you are using PostgreSQL, why did you add the MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server tags to your question?

Comment: Dan Guzman, i did so that i can get some help

Comment: @ArsalanSherwani Do not use tags which are not related to your question in any way.

Comment: `select t1.c1 * t2.c2 - t3.c3 from t1 join t2 on ... join t3 on ...`

Comment: Thanks for the genuine reply. I have a table with like 5 columns . In 5th column, I want to do operations based upon data of column 3 data and column 4 data

Comment: For query questions, the best way to get an answer is to: 1) add the table definitions. 2) add sample data, from each table. 3) add sample output.  **and, add the query** you are currently using

Comment: `select t2.col1,  t1.col5 * (t1.col3 + t1.col4) as x  from t1 join t2 on ...` you don't need an "index" to access the values of that column: & "operations" is an endless list of possibilities